# Show the code being executed graphically? .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently writing a C# program. There is an accompanying algorithm and I wish to show its lines of code being executed on a different panel at its point of execution.

For instance if this line is being called for execution:

```
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Tan);
```

Then it needs to be typed down or in an appropriate way shown on a panel.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Or

If there is a way that allows me to know the point of execution, that too would suffice.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I've got nothing on it actually.

Comment: Code runs very fast, you would have to have good eyes to read it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900744/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-line-number-when-executing-code-c-sharp for some links to external blogs

Comment: +1 I like your question. I don't know the answer waiting for a answer. Don't know it is possible (though debuggers do similar task) But definitely it is going to be very hard:)

Comment: Its for a very simple algorithm. I could pan down the rate of execution to a perceivable rate and thereafter get it onto the panel. That's what I intend to do.

Comment: @Daniel if you want so your application should be executed step by step with low rate, or simply you want to log all the executed code?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [StackFrame Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx). Using line number of the code thats being executed you should be able to get the code line i'm sure.

- GetFileLineNumber()

> Gets the line number in the file that contains the code that is
>   executing. This information is typically extracted from the debugging
>   symbols for the executable.

- GetFileName()

> Gets the file name that contains the code that is executing. This
>   information is typically extracted from the debugging symbols for the
>   executable.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the question being asked!

Comment: I've tried a test with `StackFrame.GetFileLineNumber` but it doesn't work. Just add a `Timer` calling that method periodically and it's always `0`?

Comment: @KingKing `int lineNo = new StackFrame(0, true).GetFileLineNumber();` Try this. you should set `needFileInfo` to true :)

Comment: ^ So its quite doable?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel now it's always `30` which is the line calling `new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(0,true);`

Comment: Still don't feel like I am close to the answer....

Comment: @Daniel yes, **You're far from the answer**. I've tried scanning through all the classes in `System.Diagnostics` and looks like you can trace some **special** events, not all the code executions.

Comment: @Daniel Nobody said you're close to answer and this answer is not what you need.